# How to upload files to different subdirectory using PHP via cURL on Linux command line?

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files using PHP via curl on the command line (For now, my PHP script is only able to upload one file at a time.) All files are of the same type. But each file belongs to different school and class.

For example, the user types the following on the command line:

```
curl –F “uploadedfile=@/home/michael/test” –F “school=diamond” –F “class=alpha” http://website.com/michael/upload.php
```

File name, school and class are specified by the user.

The expected outcome is the script is able to upload the file test to the alpha directory:

`/michael/uploads/diamond/alpha`

The PHP is:

```
<?php
$target_path = “uploads/”;

//I tried to add these 3 lines, but it doesn't work
$school = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['school']);
$class = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['class']);
$target_path = $target_path . $school . "/" . $class . "/" . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);    

//$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES[‘uploadedfile’][‘name’]);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[‘uploadedfile’][‘tmp_name’], $target_path)) {
echo “The file”. basename( $_FILES[‘uploadedfile’][‘name’]. “ has been uploaded”;
} else {
echo “There was an error uploading the file, please try again!”;
}
?>
```

After reading the manual, I noticed that I can't do `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['school']`and `['class']`.How could I modify my PHP script so that it can capture the school and class and upload the file to the class subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the –F "uploadedfile=@/home/michael/test" of the curl command will be retrieved in the superglobal $_FILES array, the other –F "school=diamond" –F "class=alpha" will appear in the $_POST array.

In your script, you should replace :

```
    $school = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['school']);
    $class = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['class']);
```

by

```
    $school = $_POST['school'];
    $class = $_POST['class'];
```